# How to return only queried items from table?

Tags: sql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, postman, h2

I have an H2 database ran in a spring-boot application with the following table of data.

[image]

I am able to send get requests from postman to get the entire output of the table.

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "category": "AI",
    "title": "AI 2021",
    "content": "Potential to take over the world"
  },
  {
    "id": 33,
    "category": "Sports",
    "title": "Super Bowl",
    "content": "What a boring game"
  },
  {
    "id": 65,
    "category": "Sports",
    "title": "Cleveland Browns",
    "content": "Future Cahmpions"
  },
  {
    "id": 66,
    "category": "Sports",
    "title": "Cleveland Browns",
    "content": "Future Cahmpions"
  },
  {
    "id": 67,
    "category": "Sports",
    "title": "Cleveland Browns",
    "content": "Future Cahmpions"
  },
  {
    "id": 68,
    "category": "Sports",
    "title": "",
    "content": ""
  },
  {
    "id": 69,
    "category": "Sports",
    "title": null,
    "content": null
  },
  {
    "id": 70,
    "category": "Sports",
    "title": "aasdf",
    "content": "asdfasdav"
  },
  {
    "id": 97,
    "category": "Sports",
    "title": "Fitness Life Hack",
    "content": "Get Ripped"
  },
  {
    "id": 98,
    "category": "Sports",
    "title": "Spring FCS Games",
    "content": "Wish this happened every year"
  },
  {
    "id": 99,
    "category": "Sports",
    "title": "Football",
    "content": "Sometimes called soccer"
  },
  {
    "id": 100,
    "category": "Sports",
    "title": "Rocket League",
    "content": "That's a real sport right?"
  },
  {
    "id": 101,
    "category": "Education",
    "title": "Engineering",
    "content": "Get Smart"
  },
  {
    "id": 102,
    "category": "Education",
    "title": "Math",
    "content": "2+2=4"
  }
]
```

When I try to add a query string at the end for example http://localhost:8080/Posts/?category=Sports I still get the same output.

I've tried querying for id and other variables and nothing seems to make a difference I always get the entire table as output. I am trying to get it to only return the values where category equals sports. I know findAll() is not the right method for this. I have tried findCategory() from reading the JPQL docs but I was not able to get that to compile. Is there a method I am missing that I should be using?

```
PostRepository.java    
package com.open.forum;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;

interface PostRepository extends JpaRepository<Post, Long> {

}

PostController.java
package com.open.forum;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.DeleteMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PutMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;


@RestController
class PostController {

  private final PostRepository repository;

  PostController(PostRepository repository) {
    this.repository = repository;
  }


  // Aggregate root
  // tag::get-aggregate-root[]
  @GetMapping("/Posts")
  @ResponseBody
  List<Post> all(@RequestParam String category) {
    return repository.findAll();
  }
  
  // end::get-aggregate-root[]

  @PostMapping("/Posts")
  Post newPost(@RequestBody Post newPost) {
    return repository.save(newPost);
  }

  // Single item
  
  @GetMapping("/Posts/{id}")
  Optional<Post> one(@PathVariable Long id) {
    
    return repository.findById(id);
//      .orElseThrow(() -> new PostNotFoundException(id));
  }

  @PutMapping("/Posts/{id}")
  Post replacePost(@RequestBody Post newPost, @PathVariable Long id) {
    
    return repository.findById(id)
      .map(Post -> {
        Post.setCategory(newPost.getCategory());
        Post.setTitle(newPost.getTitle());
        Post.setContent(newPost.getContent());
        return repository.save(Post);
      })
      .orElseGet(() -> {
        newPost.setId(id);
        return repository.save(newPost);
      });
  }

  @DeleteMapping("/Posts/{id}")
  void deletePost(@PathVariable Long id) {
    repository.deleteById(id);
  }
}

Post.java
package com.open.forum;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity
public class Post {
    
    @Id 
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private String category;
    private String title;
    private String content;
    
    Post() {}
    
    public Post(String category, String title, String content) {
        this.category = category;
        this.title = title;
        this.content = content;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getCategory() {
        return category;
    }
    public void setCategory(String category) {
        this.category = category;
    }
    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }
    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }
    public String getContent() {
        return content;
    }
    public void setContent(String content) {
        this.content = content;
    }

}
```

Comment: Is your java method receiving the parameter in the URL? Print it out to make sure you are getting it. Second, are you using the parameter when running the query, in order to filter rows?

Comment: provide your code as well

Comment: Added my PostRepository, PostController and Post classes to the post. I and having a hard time getting findByCategory to work.

Comment: return repository.findByCategory(String category); it wont compile, paste actual code

Comment: Updated the code to what I had that was compiling. I need to figure out how to get from findAll to findByCategory or somthing like that I was looking at the documentation for JPQL queries and I'm not sure how to get it to work.

Comment: you have   @GetMapping("/Posts")
  @ResponseBody
  List<Post> all(@RequestParam String category) {
    return repository.findAll();
  } so whatever category you pass it returns the whole table.

Comment: Yes I’m not sure what to change it to from findAll() I tried findCategory(category) but that won’t compile it seemed like that should work from the JPQL documentation but I think I’m missing something

Comment: I figured it out in order to use the findByCategory() method I needed to declare it in the PostRepostory class with the following line List<Post> findByCategory(String category);

Comment: Hi @EZSlapdown welcome to the community. Great you found the solution. Likewise, you can do **findByTitle** or even put your custom query in your repository interface if the defaults are not enough. In addition, you can check on how to use [JpaSpecificationExecutor](https://www.baeldung.com/rest-api-search-language-spring-data-specifications) which allows you to build queries programmatically :)